# Knockout computed not firing subscription

Tags: knockout.js

This is my code:

```
self.convertedPrice = ko.computed(function () {
    console.debug('Calculating convertedPrice');
    if (self.ProductListPrice() != null && self.multiplicationFactor() != null) {
        return self.ProductListPrice() * self.multiplicationFactor();
    }

    return 0;
}).extend({notify:'always'});

self.convertedPrice.subscribe(function (newVal) {
    console.debug('convertedPrice subscription fired.');
    self.discountedPrice(parseFloat(newVal).toFixed(2));
});
```

When `self.ProductListPrice` is updated, `self.convertedPrice` correctly updates and the first debug is written, but the subscription isn't fired so the second debug statement is never written and `self.discountedPrice` is not updated.

I've worked round this for now by moving the contents of the subscription into the computed code, but I'd like to understand why the original subscription didn't work. If I changed either `self.ProductListPrice` or `self.multiplicationFactor` manually, the subscription fired, but when they changed as a result of the rest of my code and user input, the subscription didn't fire.

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: if you want to make subscribe to fire when computed computes just slightly teak it computed . use `deferEvaluation:true` sample here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26144/

Comment: I had already tried deferring the evaluation while trying to track this down myself, but it didn't make any difference. Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 3):

My only guess is that you're doing an assignment instead of calling the observables when setting a value. The code below works as expected.

```js
function viewModel() {
  var self = {
    discountedPrice: ko.observable(),
    ProductListPrice: ko.observable(),
    multiplicationFactor: ko.observable()
  };
  self.convertedPrice = ko.computed(function() {
    console.debug('Calculating convertedPrice');
    if (self.ProductListPrice() != null && self.multiplicationFactor() != null) {
      return self.ProductListPrice() * self.multiplicationFactor();
    }

    return 0;
  }).extend({
    notify: 'always'
  });

  self.convertedPrice.subscribe(function(newVal) {
    console.debug('convertedPrice subscription fired.');
    self.discountedPrice(parseFloat(newVal).toFixed(2));
  });
  return self;
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div><label>List Price</label><input data-bind="value:ProductListPrice" /></div>
<div><label>Multiplier</label><input data-bind="value:multiplicationFactor" /></div>
<div><label>Converted</label> <span data-bind="text:convertedPrice"></span></div>
<div><label>Discounted</label> <span data-bind="text:discountedPrice"></span></div>
```

Comment: When you say doing an assignment, do you mean using (for example) `self.multiplicationFactor = 3;` instead of `self.multiplicationFactor(3);`? I know that's not happening as the variables are all still observables, but not sure if I've misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: @Tim You understood correctly. It's also possible (though unlikely) you're doing something like `self.multiplicationFactor = ko.observable(3)`, which would leave it an observable, but a different, unbound one. I can only say that the code you included here doesn't have a problem.

Comment: That's a fair comment, I'll check I haven't done anything silly like that.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid the null checks? Having to do it on every computed observable seems like an anti-pattern.  I've not found a solution yet.

Comment: You can write it different ways (e.g. `return (obs1() || 0) * (obs2() || 0)`), but I don't think you can get around handling the edge cases.